# Meaning of "zero configuration credntial blob"

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I am planning to use spotify embedded SDK to develop something. But in few of the API's of .h file  I see "zero_conf_blob" as parameter. Can anyone please explain me what is the meaning of "blob" in spotify app?

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify Embedded SDK is not a publicly available SDK. Technical support for it is available through your Spotify contact.